# How to stop executor service threads even when their task is not completed?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I started some threads using Executor Service for getting some files from network.I want the Threads to stop execution after some time duration even if their run method is not completed.
How to do that? Even executors' shutdown() and awaitTermination(...) methods did not work.

Comment: This appears to be a specific case of the general question, "how to stop any threads". I believe that the solution is the same, to have code in the threaded code that allows for it to be interrupted or stopped.

Comment: Haven't you tried `Future.get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)` ?

Comment: @VishalK Even if the future time out (and gets cancelled), Hovercraft's point still holds; the thread will continue running in the background if it doesn't know how to stop itself.

Comment: @CoryKendall: If the `TimeoutException` is caught , then in `catch` block user can cancel thread using `Future.cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning)` .. isn't it?

Comment: @VishalK Yes, but the thread itself is still still responsible for checking `isCancelled` and stopping what its doing.  Otherwise the thread is "cancelled" and will just keep running.

Comment: @CoryKendall: yes, right So the underlying `thread` would be entirely responsible for its `quit` by checking the `interruption` condition... Got it..Thanks :).. But I wonder that why `ExecutorService.shutdownNow()` would not achieve this halt!!!??

Comment: @VishalK I'll stop responding now, as stackoverflow doesn't like discussions in comments, but feel free to post a Question and I'm sure you will get good answers from those smarter than me!

Comment: @CoryKendall: yeah I too got the same stuffs from SO..Nice to share ideas with you...see ya. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple answer is that you can't.  Thread.stop() was deprecated a long (long long) time ago because it was unreliable and was prone to leaving dirty resources behind.

The only other thing you can do, is have your thread pause during its workload and check for exit conditions (like being interrupted, or exceeding some predefined time limit).